# Podio API PHP get revision difference doesnt return external_id

Tags: php, podio

The PHP API for getting revision difference returns an empty value for `external_id` while I tried the sandbox in the API documents the `external_id` has values on it.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: it returns this

`array(6) {
      ["field_id"] => int(165320671)
      ["type"] => string(8) "category"
      ["external_id"] => int(0)
      ["label"] => string(18) "Send Customer Docs"
      ["from"]=> [],
      ["to"] => []
    }`

Comment: If you get the field_id listed there, what does it return? Such as with: https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-field-22353